# highchart bargraph rectangles remove stroke

Tags: highcharts

I was trying to implement progress-bar/status-bar in highchart, need to show 2 colors for the progress bar/status bar one background color and another color for status/progress, achieved using stacking bar in highchart but first rectangle in that
have white stroke color so it differentiating 2 rectangles but i need to show it as single rectangle instead of 2,Is there anyway to remove that white stroke color to show as single one.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="highchart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 100px; max-width: 200px; height: 50px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<script>
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickColor: '#FFFFFF',
            tickWidth: 1,
            categories: [''],
            labels:{
                        enabled: false
                },
            visible:false
        },
        title:{
            text:''
        },
        yAxis: {
             gridLineColor: '#FFFFFF',
             minorGridLineWidth: 0,
             lineColor: '#FFFFFF',
             gridLineWidth: 0,
             title: {
                text: ''
             },
             labels:{
                    enabled: false
             },
             visible:false
        },
        exporting: { enabled: false },
        legend:{
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
                enabled: false
        },
        colors:['#999999', '#8BF30D', '#FFFFFF'],
        series: [
        {
            name: '',
            data: [1]
        }, {
            name: '',
            data: [5]
        },{
            name: '',
            data: [0]
        }]
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should be able to use borderWidth parameter that is described in Highcharts API:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.borderWidth

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    borderWidth: 0
  }
},
```

When you will use this parameter you will be able to eliminate white border from your columns. I have made an example how your chart will work using this option:

http://jsfiddle.net/rvj65mor/1/